# Google App Engine HTTP header Content-Type not correct once application is deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am writing an app on GAE and I have a URL that will always return XML and set the Content-Type to `"text/xml; charset=utf-8"`.

I am using the built in webapp framework and using the following code to set content type and return XML in the web handler:

```
self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type',"text/xml; charset=utf-8")
self.response.out.write(template.render("my_xml",{"key1":"val1"}))
```

This works fine on the local development environment but once I deploy to the Google servers the content type is always set to `"text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

How do I make sure that correct `Content-Type` is set once it runs on the Google servers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"`, so that you override the content-type rather than adding another homonymous header.

Comment: A little late to the party but thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is it possible to change 'Sever' header by doing this?