# Google App Engine changes content-type to text/html even though it is set to application/xml

Tags: google-app-engine, go

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992180/google-app-engine-http-header-content-type-not-correct-once-application-is-deplo) but that answer applies to python applications. I'd like to know how to fix the issue for go applications.

I've deployed a web service on Google App Engine which is consumed by mobile clients. Using the function below, I send the response either as XML or JSON (as requested by the client)

```
func (api *API) Respond(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, body interface{}, status int) {

    var contentType string
    var content []byte
    var err error

    if r.Header.Get("Accept") == "application/xml" {

        contentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
        content, err = xml.Marshal(body)

    } else {

        contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        content, err = json.MarshalIndent(body, "", "  ")
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    w.WriteHeader(status)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    w.Write(content)
}
```

In either case, however, the client device receives a Content-Type of `text/html`. How can I fix this? Here's the app.yam file for my application:

```
application: wks-api
version: 3
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: api
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation in https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter , and I quote:

> Changing the header after a call to WriteHeader (or Write) has no
>   effect

Now look at your code:

```
w.WriteHeader(status)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
```

as you see, you *are* indeed "Changing the header after a call to WriteHeader" -- hence, it "has no effect".

So, do your "changing the header" **before** that call instead:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
w.WriteHeader(status)
```

I don't think this is at all specific to app engine -- it should apply to any use of `http` in Go.

Comment: It feels so obvious now! Thanks

Comment: @W.K.S, you're welcome! I hope you will now accept this answer as per usual Stack etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

See information from [http/header](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/):

> WriteHeader sends an HTTP response header with status code. If
>   WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write will
>   trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK). Thus explicit calls
>   to WriteHeader are mainly used to send error codes.

first try settings the header then send it